# What does the datasize limit in a csh actually do?

Tags: linux, csh

My .cshrc had set up a "limit datasize 256000", however several of my running processes are currently exceeding that.  For example:

```
VmPeak:   496840 kB
VmSize:   496840 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:    463408 kB
VmRSS:    463408 kB

VmData:   451552 kB

VmStk:        96 kB
VmExe:      7480 kB
VmLib:     35548 kB
VmPTE:       988 kB
StaBrk: 0a2bb000 kB
Brk:    19c90000 kB
StaStk: ffd4f010 kB
```

I had thought the process would fail upon encountering that limit, but obviously that didn't happen.  So I'm unsure what that datasize limit is doing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Since this is set in the .cshrc, then that means it's limited to that session.  I'm thinking that somehow these processes must be running under a different session and are therefore not bound by that limit.

Comment: It's not an issue with running under a different session.  I've read some other documents online that imply that either the datasize is not actually enforced by the kernel or the initial size of memory allocated to the process is large enough that brk() or sbrk() is not actually getting more memory from the OS and therefore the point of enforcement of the limit is never exercised.  Still not certain exactly what's going on here.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/804997/dpkg-error-processing-package-libc-bin-configure Filler,Filler,Filler,Filler,Filler,Filler,Filler